# Getting PDF Version using Python

Tags: python, pdfminer

I need to extract the PDF version from a PDF document. I tried PDF miner but it provides the below info only:

1. PDF Producer
2. Created
3. Modified
4. Application

Below is the code I tried:

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument

fp = open("ibs.servlets.pdf", 'rb')
parser = PDFParser(fp)
doc = PDFDocument(parser)
parser.set_document(doc)
if len(doc.info) > 0:
   info = doc.info[0]
   print(info)
```

Is there any other libraries apart  from pdf miner I can use?

Comment: You could [use `pypdf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76188966/562769)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDF version is stored as a comment in the first line of the PDF file. I couldn't find how to get this information using pdfparser, but using [PyPDF2](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2) I could retrieve this information manually:

```py
from PyPDF2.pdf import PdfFileReader
doc = PdfFileReader('ibs.servlets.pdf')
doc.stream.seek(0) # Necessary since the comment is ignored for the PDF analysis
print(doc.stream.readline().decode())
```

Output:

```py
%PDF-1.5
```

Comment: Thanks @Frodon. To add to this, can we get the full version of the PDF like this: 1.4 (Acrobat 5.x)

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to accept my answer 