# Extracting PDF Version using Python

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I attempted to follow [Getting PDF Version using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65075099) to extract the version from a PDF file and unfortunately resulted in an error code.

I'm new to Python and have no idea how to fix this.  I can view the PDF file in something like Notepad and see that it is the first line and something like %PDF-1.4 but don't know how to extract it.

The code I used was as follows:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
doc = PdfReader(filepath)
doc.stream.seek(0) # Necessary since the comment is ignored for the PDF analysis
print(doc.stream.readline().decode())
```

I expected the result to be:
%PDF-1.4

I received the error code:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 10: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Well, there is no need to create a PdfReader here. You're just reading the first line of a file which happens to be a PDF. So you can use the ordinary file reading facilities of Python for this. Not sure why you would want to, though - PyPDF2 almost certainly has a function to return the PDF version. (In any event, a PDF header can be preceded by up to 1024 bytes of junk, so your code isn't going to work for all PDFs anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PyPDF2` is deprecated. Use `pypdf`:

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
print(reader.pdf_header)
```

gives something like `'%PDF-1.4'`.

However, I don't see any reason to do that. PDF Generators typically just set a constant within the file. Meaning this version can be wrong in two directions:

- The PDF documents header claims the document is in version X, but actually uses newer features (that should be rarely the case). Meaning it should give version y with `x < y`.
- The PDF documents header  claims the document is in version X, but actually uses only older features. That means it could denote an older version y with `x > y`.

I don't know if any software makes use of the version being denoted.